# Applying same formatting to multiple borders in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, performance

Is there a better way to format the cells with borders than what you get when you record a macro?  For example, I want to add borders to a cell range.  The recorded code is:

```
Range("A1:C19").Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
```

Can this be shortened?

Comment: Yes, it can be shortened but it depends on which border attributes you want to change.  More information on how you want the borders to be formatted will be helpful.

Comment: Like in the code, the top, bottom, right and left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is "how do I apply the same formatting to multiple borders?" then the following is one way:

```
Dim the_borders As Variant
the_borders = Array(xlEdgeLeft, xlEdgeTop, xlEdgeBottom, xlEdgeRight, xlInsideVertical, xlInsideHorizontal)
    ' Or whatever xlEdge* constants you want to list

Dim idx As Long
For idx = LBound(the_borders) To UBound(the_borders)
    With Selection.Borders(the_borders(idx))     ' Process the right border
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
Next idx
```

The `As Variant` / `Array` combo gives you an array of the border IDs you specify, running from `LBound(the_borders)` to `UBound(the_borders)`.  Then, within the loop, `borders(idx)` is the `XlBordersIndex` you can pass to `Selection.Borders`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use. I added the selection range so you get intellisense.

```
Dim selectionRange As Range
Set selectionRange = Selection

Dim theLineStyle As XlLineStyle
theLineStyle = xlContinuous

With selectionRange
    .BorderAround theLineStyle 
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = theLineStyle
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = theLineStyle
end With
```

Comment: Not bad, although I would recommend using `Selection.Range` instead of `selectionRange` --- you will still have IntelliSense and you won't need an extra variable :) .